# Unable to fetch the Youtube Username using Javascript ( Chrome Extension )

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, youtube, web-mining

I am trying to learn how to create chrome extensions. Creating a simple extension which console logs the title of the current youtube video

This is the HTML for the Youtube Title

```
<div id="title" class="style-scope ytd-watch-metadata">
    <ytd-badge-supported-renderer class="style-scope ytd-watch-metadata" disable-upgrade="" hidden="">
    </ytd-badge-supported-renderer>
    <h1 class="style-scope ytd-watch-metadata">
      <yt-formatted-string force-default-style="" class="style-scope ytd-watch-metadata">Elon’s "based" Grok AI has entered the chat…</yt-formatted-string>
    </h1>
    <ytd-badge-supported-renderer class="style-scope ytd-watch-metadata" disable-upgrade="" hidden="">
    </ytd-badge-supported-renderer>
  </div>
```

This is the code I have written to fetch the title. This code is in the ContentScript.

```
(()=>{
    console.log(document.getElementById("title"));
    console.log(document.querySelector("#title > h1 > yt-formatted-string"));
})();
```

The first line gives the output

```
<div id="title" class="style-scope ytd-watch-metadata">
```

But the second line outputs

```
null
```

I have checked and the second line gives the correct output when typed in the chrome console. It doesn't work when I'm trying to do it using javascript.

Here is my manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "FillModule",
    "description": "Fill test 001",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "permissions": ["storage", "tabs"],
    "author":"Aniket Vishwakarma",
    "action": {
        "default_icon": "assets/doggy.png",
        "default_title": "Fill",
        "default_popup": "popup/popup.html"
    },
    "background" : {
        "service_worker": "background/background.js"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["https://*.youtube.com/*"],
          "js": ["content/content.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

**MY ATTEMPTS**

I have tried to wrap it in a "DOMContentLoaded" like so

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    console.log(document.querySelector("#title > h1 > yt-formatted-string"));
    console.log(document.getElementById("title"));
});
```

But then none of the lines execute.

I found a solution on StackOverflow for why the "DOMContentLoaded" was not working. That solution went like this

```
if (document.readyState !== 'loading') init();
else document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);

function init() {
    console.log(document.getElementById("title"));
    console.log(document.querySelector("#title > h1 > yt-formatted-string"));
}
```

But then I get the same result

```
<div id="title" class="style-scope ytd-watch-metadata">
null
```

Can someone explain what's happening here and how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, the title is being loaded after the initial page load using javascript.

What you can do is wait for the selector to become available.

```
function waitForSelector(selector) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
      return resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
    }

    const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
      if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
        resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
        observer.disconnect();
      }
    });

    observer.observe(document.body, {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true,
    });
  });
}

waitForSelector("#title > h1 > yt-formatted-string").then((el) => console.log(el));
```